# Team moving from TFS to GIT

Tags: git

The team I work on is using primarily TFS ([Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx))  on most projects and we're slowly moving to Git. With that said, some of us devs seem to be overriding each other. We have a "**Master**" and "**Develop**" branch. Any feedback that can help is greatly appreciated.

**The question is**: Do you see any problems with this process that we're trying to follow?

This is what our process is:

- Checkout "**develop**" branch
- Create "**develop-feature**" branch
- Make changes to "**develop-feature**" branch
- Commit changes to "**develop-feature**" branch
- Checkout "**develop**" branch and pull for updates
- Checkout "**develop-feature**" branch
- Run command "**git rebase develop**"
- Fix any merge conflicts if any
- Checkout "**develop**" branch
- Run command "**git merge --squash develop-feature**"

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry. The question is: Do you see any problems with this process that we're trying to follow?

Comment: What branch reflects what's in production? Which branch do you deploy to production? Do you merge develop into master when deploy? What happens if I have a feature branch merged into develop but not fully tested yet and ready to go to prod, then you merge your feature branch into develop and you are ready to go to prod? Is develop the branch deployed to a staging environment for testing?

Comment: @LukeHutton - This is a new project so we don't have PROD yet, but yes "master" branch is our "PROD" trunk. If you have merged your feature into "develop" that's not fully tested, I guess you would either have to continue development on that user story in "develop" or finish your code in the "feature" branch and merge once your development is done. We can create environment specific branches like "develop-qa" to promote code to for "QA" testing. We were trying to follow the "Git Flow" process if that means anything.

Comment: Yah that strategy seems ok to me, you can always "refactor" your strategy if problems do ever arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost exactly the same procedure I use when pushing to the main line from my development repository.  The 'Fix any merge conflicts' step should also check if the pull and rebase broke anything.  I assume after the squash merge there will be a 'git push' to publish the develop-feature changes.

see also

```
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/
```

for other work flows

Comment: Yes, after the merge would be a push to "origin/develop". Thank you for the comparing-workflow info. I read over it and feel it's pretty close to our process being used.

Comment: Find some good basic stuff in 'git help -g'.  See especially 'workflows', and 'everyday', sections.